# Razor all clips in timeline underneath in/out points

Tags: premiere

I've just synched a lot of clips using PluralEyes, and imported this in PPCC. Since I'm relatively new to this program (using Vegas earlier), I wanted to check if there is a way to automatically razor all clips in the timeline underneath my I/O selection?

Now I have to set the I/O points (or just go straigth to the razor tool), select the razor tool, hold shift and use the IO points as reference to cut all the clips underneath my mouse cursor.

I want to find a way to quickly make rough selection and cut out all the surrounding stuff. It was quite easy in Vegas by just making lots of regions, and using a Vegas script to cut out all the surrounding stuff ... is there a workflow like that in PP?

Comment: **shift+ctl/cmd+k** will add a cut right across all cuts in your timeline, so you could do **shift+i**, **shift+ctl/cmd+k**, then **shift+o**, **shift+ctl/cmd+k** to quickly add cuts at your in and out points. But listen to @AJHenderson and use multicam instead.

Answer (score 2):

Don't even try to do it this way.  For what you are trying to do, take a look at the multi-camera editing mode.  It is designed for doing precisely the kind of thing you are trying to do in a much simpler way.  You can find more detail about the multi-cam features in Adobe's own documentation [here](http://helpx.adobe.com/premiere-pro/using/create-multi-camera-source-sequence.html).